# Powershell - Find and Replace then Save

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to read 10K+ files, search the files line by line, for the string of characters after the word **`SUFFIX`**.  Once I capture that string I need to remove all traces of it from the file then re-save the file.
With the example below - I would capture `-4541`.  Then I would replace all occurrences of `-4541` with NULL.
Once I replace all the occurrences I then save the changes.

Here is my Data:

```
ABSDOMN                                  VER     1 D  SUFFIX -4541

         05 ST-CTY-CDE-FMHA-4541
          10 ST-CDE-FMHA-4541                        9(2)
          10 CTY-CDE-FMHA-4541                       9(3)
         05 NME-CTY-4541                             X(20)
         05 LST-UPDTE-DTE-4541                       9(06)
         05 FILLER                                   X
```

Here is a starting script.  I can Display the line that has the word SUFFIX but I cannot capture the string after it.  In this case `-4541`.

```
$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\IDMS" -File -Recurse 
$regex = "\bSUFFIX\b" 
$treat = $false 
ForEach($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
    Write-Host "Processing .... $CBLFile" -foregroundcolor green      
    Get-content -Path $CBLFile.FullName |
    ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -match $regex) {
                Write-Host "Found Match - $_" -foregroundcolor green
                $treat=$true
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Is the suffix always on the first line? If not, do you need to remove instances of the suffix on _preceding lines_, or only the lines after the "SUFFIX" line?

Comment: Do you really want to replace with NULL, or do you want to replace it with an equal amount of spaces? If you replace it with NULL it will throw off nicely lined up columns.

Comment: For future reference, please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Your current code has syntax errors (`} $regex  =`) and unfinished statements.

Comment: The Suffix is always on the first line.
Either Null or Spaces is fine
I keep trying to reformat the code to display correctly and it keeps displaying it as you see it.
I Deleted the code, re-added it and then wrapped it in "CODE" markers and it still displays as you see it.  Must be a bad character in there somewhere 

-Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Note: Be sure to make backup copies of the input files first, as they will be updated in place. Use `-Encoding` with `Set-Content` to specify the desired encoding, if it should be different from `Set-Content`'s default.

```
$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\IDMS" -File -Recurse 
$regex = '(?<=SUFFIX) -\d+'
ForEach ($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
  $firstLine, $remainingLines = $CBLFile | Get-Content
  if ($firstLine -cmatch $regex) {
    $toRemove = $Matches[0].Trim()
    & { $firstLine -creplace $regex; $remainingLines -creplace $toRemove } |
      Set-Content -LiteralPath $CBLFile.FullName
  }
}
```

<sup>Based on your feedback, the regex that worked for you in the end was `(?<=SUFFIX).*$` (which could be simplified to `(?<=SUFFIX).+` in this case), i.e. one that captures *whatever follows* substring `SUFFIX`, instead of only capturing a space followed by a `-` and one or more digits (`\d+`).</sup>